# Monad reader and partial application of functions

Tags: monads, purescript

Since partially applied functions [are instances of the `MonadReader`](https://github.com/purescript/purescript-transformers/blob/v2.2.0/src/Control/Monad/Reader/Class.purs#L41), why is the following code incorrect?

```
runReader (\x -> x + 2) 4
```

or even

```
runReader (\x -> pure $ x + 2) 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being an instance of `MonadReader` allows you to use the "reader operations" (`local`, `ask`, `asks`), but `runReader` is explicitly for running a type of `Reader`.

So for example, you can do this because of `monadReaderFun`:

```
readerFunction :: Int -> Int
readerFunction = do
  x <- ask
  pure (x + 2)
```

But there's no need to "run" it, the way you do with a `Reader` or `ReaderT` typed value.